# Default indent line guide in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any built in Indent Guide in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: For regular VS 2017: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736094/visual-studio-2017-indent-guide-coloring

Answer (score 156, accepted):

We just released this in the [June 2016 release (v1.3.0)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/June_2016#_editor). You can enable it by adding the following to your `settings.json` file (<kbd>F1</kbd>, `Open Settings (JSON)`):

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true
```

For anything more customizable indent guides you will need an extension such as [Guides](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spywhere.guides).

Comment: @DanielImms How can this be controlled with a keyboard shortcut to toggle it off and on?

Comment: @BobRockefeller you'll need an extension something like this that allows you to toggle settings https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-settings-cycler

Answer (score 12):

As of the [September 2021 (version 1.61)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_indentation-guides-settings) release, the correct setting is now:

```json
"editor.guides.indentation": true
```

[image: editor.guides.indentation setting in UI]

The old setting from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35788977/2745495) has been deprecated:

> #### Indentation guides settings
>
> The `editor.renderIndentGuides` and `editor.highlightActiveIndentGuide`
> settings have been deprecated in favor of `editor.guides.indentation`
> and `editor.guides.highlightActiveIndentation`.

Answer (score 3):

**Default indent line guide**

- **Method-1  (using settings.json)**

  `"editor.renderIndentGuides": false,` is now **deprecated** in vs
  code.

  Use  `"editor.guides.indentation": true` instead.

  [image]
- **Method-2  (using settings UI)**

  Goto settings > search `editor.guides.indentation`  > Add 'tip' mark
  for guides indentation.

  [image]

---

**Custom indent line guide**

Using the below extensions, you can add custom indent guides

[Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SirTori.indenticator)