# VSCode scope line mark detection

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vs-community-edition

I just trying to switch my editor from NetBeans to VSCode, however there is one feature which i missed from NetBeans and seem not exist at VSCode. I am not sure what is the name of the feature, i just call it "Scope mark line". The detail is like picture attached.

My question is, is there any plugins can bring that feature to VSCode? Please let me know if any, thanks in advance.

[image: Scope line mark at netbeans editor]

Comment: I haven't seen any extension that does such a markup. The only thing you can try is to go through the vscode marketplace and see what extensions exist. You can filter the list there so that you don't get a too big list to check.

Comment: @MikeLischke : Thank you for your advice.  I still can't find it there. Not sure what keyword should i use. Really wonder that feature exist in VSCode, it is helpful for very long multiple line code.

Answer (score 3):

I also had a hard time searching for this feature, and found this VS Code Extension on the Marketplace: [guides](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spywhere.guides) which adds various indentation guide lines. This worked for me editing ruby and bash files on osx.

Some of the tags for the extension: 
guides indentation indentation guides ruler

Comment: While this may answer the question, link only answers are frowned upon as links can expire or change making them invalid. Please edit your answer to include the core information from you link.

Answer (score 0):

From [Default indent line guide in Visual Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741301/default-indent-line-guide-in-visual-code)

Enable in `settings.json`:

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true
```