# What are these straight lines that connect the start and the end of while and if-else statements?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have it in Sublime, but not in VS Code, how can I add them in VS Code?

[image: screeshot]

I tried to find the name of this, but failed.

Comment: I call them indentation/nesting guides. Don't know what's the official name.

Comment: Looks like there is an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645976/vscode-scope-line-mark-detection

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code they are called Guides. Just open the settings and search for them. I assume you want either Indentation Guides or Bracket Pair guides:
[image: Guides settings]