# Visual Studio 2017 Indent Guide Coloring

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015, I had coloring for the indent guides like this.

I can't seem to find this feature in Visual Studio 2017.  Is there an extension that does this?

There's an option in the Fonts and Colors to change the color for all Guidelines.  But what I want is the same in 2015 where it's automatically color coded (blue, green, teal, purple, etc.) depending on the type/level of the braces.

[image]

Comment: @GSerg There's an option in the Fonts and Colors to change the color for all Guidelines.  But what I want is the same in 2015 where it's automatically color coded (blue, green, teal, purple, etc.) depending on the type/level of the braces.  What you linked just changes the color for all.

Comment: For others like me that couldn't even find the color setting, it's "Structure Guide Lines".

Comment: **To turn it off:** `Tools => Options => Text Editor => General => Uncheck "Show structure guidelines"` (http://dailydotnettips.com/2017/07/20/turning-onoff-structure-guide-lines-in-visual-studio-2017/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is just what you want.This is that extension called "Indent Guides".

The number behind the '#' on behalf of the different level of the Indent Guides.

I know my answer looks terrible. Please forgive me. As a new one here, i really try my best.

[image: Here is what it looks like]
[image: Here is how i change the color of the indent guides which belongs to different level]
[image: Follow the step above]

Answer (score 6):

Native in VS2017. It's called "Structure Guide Lines"

[image]

Comment: **To turn it off:** `Tools => Options => Text Editor => General => Uncheck "Show structure guidelines"` (http://dailydotnettips.com/2017/07/20/turning-onoff-structure-guide-lines-in-visual-studio-2017/)

Comment: You seem not to have read the question. VS 2017 and 2019's native guide lines lack color-coding, and therefore do not do what Jack is asking.

Comment: This is a general way for hiding the Structure Guide Lines and Outlining.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such feature built into VS2015. It is added by extensions.

Eg. the "Structure Visualiser" from [Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2015).

However for 2017 there is a (lesser) feature built in, so the Productivity PowerTools 2017 does not include this feature. (It is now also a set of separate extentions rather than a monolithic tool.)

This is explained in a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/03/06/productivity-power-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/) see section *What's Missing?*

Comment: Thanks.  That's unfortunate.  The color coding was useful.

Comment: [IndentGuides](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides) version works for me in VS 2017 - ignore warning, that it is not compatible.

Answer (score 3):

There is also an excellent extension for Visual Studio 2015 called [Indent Guides](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides) that is working really well.

It is not compatible with VS2017 by default, but you can get around that by modifying the extension manifest file within the `vsix` file:

```
1) Download IndentGuide v14.vsix for VS2015
2) Use 7-zip (or other archive utility) to open the .vsix file (which is actually a .zip)
3) Edit the extension.vsixmanifest file within the .vsix file
4) Make a copy of the whole VisualStudio Version="14.0" section
5) Change that new copy to VisualStudio Version="15.0"
6) Save the manifest, save the vsix.
7) Double-click the .vsix file to install it.  Ignore the compatibility warning.
```

Comment: Does this have the colors?

Comment: Current version works in VS2017 without modifying the manifest.  Just ignore the compatibility warning.  And yes, it has colors.

Answer (score 3):

This really should be a comment, but as I do not have enough reputation to make it, an "answer" it is.

A uservoice was added to solicit feedback on missing features of the current Structure Visualizer added to VS2017. If you have an interest in seeing these features restored, please vote.

[Improve the Structure Visualizer in Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18628639-improve-the-structure-visualizer-in-visual-studio?page=2&per_page=20)

Answer (score 1):

In the German Version of VS2017 Enterprise the setting your looking for is called "Strukturführungslinien" in Options / Environment / Fonts and Colors. I would translate it with "structurelines".

Comment: Thx! It's "Structure Guide Lines" in the english version

Comment: But that's not what's OP asking. He doesn't want to change the indentation lines color, he wants to color them automatically depending on the indentation depth or block type - different color for namespaces, classes, methods, loops, conditionals, etc. Such feature used to be provided by the Productivity Power Tools extension.