# VS Code IDE does not show line

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I add line to VS Code IDE as the right picture?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need another If statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default indent line guide in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741301/default-indent-line-guide-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

Go to File Menu > Preferences > Settings, paste `editor.guides.indentation` to the find box and check the option.

Comment: Thanks so much, it working well for me